# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'round'

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror

I quite begginer with Python and have actually a problem with numpy. When I try to import seaborn (chart visualisation) or to do a kmeans with sklearn, I have a message of error :

"AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'round'"

I don't really understand the problem.

My numpy package is version 1.23.4 and I already tried to update the package and pip but the problem keep.
Does some can help me please ?
Many thankss

Comment: Please show us your attempt!

Comment: Any chance you wrote a python script called "numpy.py"? It may be that something else with the same name is imported. You could `import numpy` and then `print(numpy.__file__)` to see where the .py file is. And `print(numpy.__version__)` to see its version.

Comment: @tdelaney has an important point that beginners overlook. Please check that before moving forward

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing the rounding yourself:

There is no numpy `round` function **but** there is a [`round_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) function.

```
np.round(arr) #does not exist
np.round_(arr) #does exist
```

If you are NOT:

Please check that you have NOT overwritten `numpy.py` somewhere on accident

Comment: At least on my numpy 1.21.5, `round` exists as an alias to `round_`.

Comment: Fair point and good comment - there's also an `around` method that seems to do the same thing. Interesting naming on their end.

Comment: np.round(data) # do work.

I show you the problem :
import seaborn as sns 

return :
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_33196\2215191008.py in <cell line: 6>()
 import seaborn as sns

c:\...\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>

---> 31     from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
...
--> 489         x = np.round(x).astype(np.intp, copy=False)
    490 
    491     if x.ndim < 3:

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'round'

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `numpy` as:

if on anaconda environment: `conda install numpy`,
else using PIP: `pip install numpy`

If the installation fails to solve the problem:

Uninstall the existing `numpy`:

- `conda remove numpy` then `conda install numpy`
- `pip uninstall numpy` then `pip install numpy`

Above solved my problem.